# How to create table in xml file using jaxb?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am newbie to JAXB.I have try to create table format in xml file using Jaxb.But it could not working as expected.

**Expected output**

```
<root>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>personalDetails</th><th>Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Ricky,anderson</td><td>Nov 1999</td><td>working</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Mackey,manson</td><td>Nov 1979</td><td>completed</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Corney,Richson</td><td>Nov 1989</td><td>pending</td></tr>   
            </tbody>
        </table>
</root>
```

So far i have tried

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "table")
public class Table {


        String table;
        String thread;
        String border;
        String width;
        String tbody;
        public String getTbody() {
            return tbody;
        }
        @XmlElement(name = "tbody")
        public void setTbody(String tbody) {
            this.tbody = tbody;
        }

        public String getThread() {
            return thread;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "thread")
        public void setThread(String thread) {
            this.thread = thread;
        }

        public String getBorder() {
            return border;
        }

        @XmlAttribute(name = "border")
        public void setBorder(String border) {
            this.border = border;
        }
        @XmlAttribute(name = "width")
        public void setWidth(String width) {
            this.width = width;
        }
        public String getWidth() {
            return width;
        }
}
```

Root Element class.Also i struggle in this class,

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "text")
public class RootTable {

    Table table;

    public Table getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(Table table) {
        this.table = table;
    }
```

Main Class

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        Table table = new Table();
        table.setThread("<tr><th>personalDetails</th><th>Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>");
        table.setWidth("15");
        table.setBorder("100");
        table.setTbody("<tr><td>Ricky,anderson</td><td>Nov 1999</td>td>working</td></tr>");
        RootTable too = new RootTable();
        too.setTable(table);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootTable.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    // output pretty printed
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    //jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(too, System.out);

            }
}
```

If i run the program it will shows following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<text>
    <table width="15" border="100">
        <tbody>&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Ricky,anderson&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Nov 1999&lt;/td&gt;td&gt;working&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;</tbody>
        <thread>&lt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th&gt;personalDetails&lt;/th&gt;&lt;th&gt;Date&lt;/th&gt;&lt;th&gt;Status&lt;/th&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;</thread>
    </table>
</text>
```

I donot know how to proceed further? Is there any other option there? can someone help me.

Comment: Did you try to run your code? What does it print?

Comment: If you ask me, although technically not wrong AFAIK, it's a bad idea to put an HTML table that way in a xml file

Comment: I would serioulsy recommend against producing HTML directly from Java classes. Instead, try to produce a clean XML format that you apply an XSLT transformation on.

Comment: Here is an example of the approach suggested by @forty-two - http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/using-jaxb-with-xslt-to-produce-html.html

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem go ahead with your modelling. You have to create classes `Tr` and `Td`, and add instances of these classes to table instead of adding full string.

However I fully agree with guys that mentioned that it is not the best idea to use JAXB for HTML generating. I do not know what is your final aim however although theoretically HTML is a subset of XML there are better tools to operate with it.

I can mention however that I personally used XML parsing technique to deal with HTML, however there were other constraints that made me to do this.

Comment: +1 - You wouldn't need a class for `Td` though as `Tr` could just have a `List<String>` mapped to the `td` element.